# Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'src': (:Node {src: null})

Tags: json, neo4j, null

I am fairly new to neo4j and I want to write a query which reads .json format and create a graph of the nodes. Below is my query which is successful in a file where there is no null property and unsuccessful when I have null property in my json file.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled.json") YIELD value  

UNWIND value.nodes as nodes

UNWIND nodes.properties as prop

MERGE(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP})
 
MERGE(n2:Node{dst:prop.destIP})  

WITH n1,n2,prop

MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2)

RETURN n1,n2,prop
```

Anyone has any idea of what might solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When creating properties in Neo4j you cannot have null properties.

There are a number of ways to work around this, but a quick option to just get some data in could be to use [coalesce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function, which will use the first non-null value it hits, e.g.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.nodes as nodes
UNWIND nodes.properties as prop
MERGE(n1:Node{src:coalesce(prop.sourceIP,"No IP")})
MERGE(n2:Node{dst:coalesce(prop.destIP, "No IP"})
WITH n1,n2,prop
MERGE (n1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(n2)
RETURN n1,n2,prop
```

Comment: Note that you can CREATE a node passing `null` for the property, it's the same as omitting the property completely (since it is true as you said that there is no such thing as a `null` value for a property). But you can't MERGE using null property values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, the issue was that the dump that I was trying to build the graph upon had some null properties and I had to ignore them to go ahead with the rest of the nodes. the "No IP" did not work but I managed to solve it
by below:

```
    call apoc.load.json("file:/graph-phase1-labelled1.json") yield value
    unwind value.nodes as nodes
    unwind nodes.properties as prop 
    with prop where prop.sourceIP is not null
    with prop where prop.destIP is not null
    merge(n1:Node{src:prop.sourceIP}) 
    merge(n2:Node{dest:prop.destIP}) 
    with prop,n1,n2
    merge (n1)-[ :connected_to]->(n2)
    return n1,n2,prop
```